# How to send extra parameters to server in Federated learning with Flower and Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, federated-learning

I want to send extra parameters with model updates to server and then utilize those extra parameters in server for other purposes. I am using Flower and Tensorflow for this project. Before sending extra parameters, my model was working perfectly. Currently I have these code[client model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9nLx.png) [server.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K82hf.png).

How do I successfully send extra parameters or values in server and receive it?

Thank you for your help.

I tried to send additional parameters in get_parameter method, and receive it with FedAvg strategy. But I got this error again and again. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeRVX.png)

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.